# Accessing the most-recently-declared label when issuing a cross-referencing command

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a way to access the key of the most-recently-declared label?

for instance:

```
    \begin{equation}\label{equ:1}
    ...
    \end{equation}

    bla bla bla \ref{\getlastlabelkey} bla bla bla ...
```

instead of:

```
    bla bla bla \ref{equ:1} bla bla bla ...
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting question- however it does sound an incredibly dangerous thing to use. What happens if you insert a labelled equation in between what is now your `equ:1` and the reference?

Comment: In that case that would obviously be a problem :)! However this was just a simple question to try and achieve a solution to this problem http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57093/automatically-position-detailed-information-about-an-equation-into-appendix

Comment: Note that the current *potential* label is located in `\@currentlabel`. This macro is set by all labelable macros like `\section`, `\caption`, `equation` etc. and written by `\label` under the given label name in the `.aux` file. If you need to do some internal stuff using `\@currentlabel` directly might be easier because it doesn't need an explicit `\label` added by the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution would be to redefine `\label` to save its argument in a global macro:

```
\let\origlabel\label% Save old definition
\def\label#1{\origlabel{#1}\gdef\lastlabel{#1}}
```

Then use:

```
\ref{\lastlabel} or \ref\lastlabel
```